# Windows Git - picking up the pieces

Tags: git, git-bash, bash

I just installed the latest version of Git for Windows, and all of my previous settings/shortcuts/aliases, etc have disappeared when I open the command shell (my preferred way of working with Git).

The old version of Bash that came with Git located my home directory to my Windows user home directory, and there I have files such as `.bashrc` and `.gitconfig` that ultimately set everything up for my Git experience.

All of my Bash config files remain in this Windows user directory, but the new install doesn't appear to be looking there for the settings information.

Can someone tell me how to recover all of this so that the new Git shell looks to these settings?

Comment: Do you mean git bash or windows CMD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Git 2.5.0 `.bashrc` no longer pointing to `%USERPROFILE%\.bashrc` under windows, so i assume you upgraded from earlier version.

The new location of the file is: `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\bash.bashrc`.
Edit the file, add the old content into it and it should work.

To view the file type this is your browser address bar:

```
file:///C:/Program%20Files/Git/etc/bash.bashrc
```

---

#### ***`Another option`***

```
 # git (windows version >2.5) is not looking for .bash_profile instead of 
 # .bash so you can simply rename your file to the new name
 mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile
```